# How to use code block in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I have the following code

```
animals=['lion','tiger','zebra']
animals.each{|a| puts a}
```

I wanted to print only tiger in this array for that I wrote something like this

```
animals.each{|a| if a==1 puts animals[a]}
```

But it's not working why?

Comment: May I know what is unclear in this question?

Comment: some one intentionally down voted every post...

Comment: vote you up your post

Comment: @sawa Actually I don't know in Ruby how the array index starts is it 0 or 1. Now it is clear that its starts from 0 editing it.

Comment: It's still not clear. How is `animals[a]==1` relevant to selecting `"tiger"`?

Comment: @sawa Now I got you, editing again.

Comment: I don't get you. How is `a==1`, or `1` relevant to `"tiger"`?

Comment: @sawa I hope this time I clarified you.

Comment: better rather than using hard coded index `index ==1` use `animals.index('tiger') #which will return exact index`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wrong you did in your case:-

```
animals.each{|a| if animals[a]==2 puts a}
```

- [**`inline if`**](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_if_else.htm) statement you put in a wrong way.
- `#each` passes element of the array,not the index. So `animals[a]` will not work. It will throw error as `no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError)`.

Do this as below using [**`Array#each_index`**](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-each_index)

```
animals=['lion','tiger','zebra']
animals.each_index{|a| puts animals[a] if animals[a] == 'tiger' }
# >> tiger
```

Comment: use `Benchmark` and see the time of execution of `each` and `each_with_index` is greater than `fetch` and `at`

Comment: @RajarshiDas Its very obvious,don't need to timed it.. :)

Comment: ...so always go for better of all possibilities...:) cheers

Comment: @RajarshiDas Here I concentrated to correct only the wrong things that OP did in his post. But sure I will meet with you in SO on some other posts.. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can play with enumerable like this:

```
animals.select{ |a| a == 'tiger' }.each{ |a| puts a }
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are looking for this

```
animals.each_with_index{|animal, index| puts animal if index==1}
```

Please not that "tiger" occurs at index 1 and not 2.

Comment: better rather than using hard coded index `index ==1` use `animals.index('tiger')`

Comment: @RajarshiDas probably the code is like if *tiger* exist then print it..so I don't think `animals[animals.index('tiger')]` or `animals.at(animals.index('tiger'))` make sense. Because if *tiger* is not present both of the line will throw errors.. So either `#each` or `each_index` is good to go.. I think

Comment: @Babai he is not searching look into his question he wants to print so `tiger` is an acceptable input....secondly if it index is changed then what happen `hard coded` is not all accepted...

Comment: @RajarshiDas It seems you didn't get my point..I am talking about this `animals.index('tiger')`..it will return *index* (if found) or `nil`(if not found). So if `nil` returned then `animals.at(animals.index('tiger'))` and `animals[animals.index('tiger')]` both will throw error,whereas `#each` or `#each_index` is safer...I think..

Comment: @Babai you did not get my point look if it is an dynamic array and index is continuously changed then your har coded index  will fail.....and look at my edited post....any case you have to check if user input is not guaranteed but here he knows that there is a 'tiger' just want to print

Comment: @RajarshiDas I am not going against hard-coded index,Yes you are right on that case. I am talking about the solution.

Comment: @Babai here he knows that there is a 'tiger' just want to print

Answer (score 0):

you can simply do this

```
 animals.fetch(animals.index('tiger')) if animals.include? 'tiger'
```

or

```
 animals[animals.index('tiger')] if animals.include? 'tiger'
```

Comment: `animals[animals.index('tiger')]` and `animals.fetch(animals.index('tiger'))` can thorw error if `tiger` not present..your `#each` version was good..Don't know why deleted that..

Comment: gurantee it will not throw error .....look I am checking included or not

Comment: @humm I have seen..then good..

Comment: `irb(main):023:0> animals.fetch(animals.index('a')) if animals.include? 'a'
=> nil`

Comment: thank you @Babai to depict conditional check